# Why is my binary search slower than my brute force?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

The performance of my brute force and searches are

- Iterative Took 0.1000 milliseconds to generate:
- Recursive Took 0.1500 milliseconds to generate:
- Brute Took 0.0800 milliseconds to generate:

I understand that recursive searches suffer from tail end optimization problems. (now I do at least), But I'm still not sure why the iterative binary search is still slower than my brute force.

Here is my code, its not the most optimized, but it shouldn't be slower.
iterative and recursive only does 6-7 loops(i forget)
and brute force has 100 loops all the time.

I've done some googling and cant figure it out.

```
    data = [[0.1430903741309869,0.09099423635474843], [0.14312849662493274,0.09181153207084017], [0.1432428032314926,0.09262882778693171], [0.14343311180983973,0.09344612350302323], [0.1436991203996287,0.09426341921911474], [0.14404040960138637,0.09508071493520626], [0.14445644584780032,0.09589801065129779], [0.14494658550706505,0.09671530636738929], [0.1455100797459424,0.09753260208348079], [0.14614608006894764,0.09834989779957232], [0.14685364444133878,0.09916719351566383], [0.14763174389751746,0.09998448923175535], [0.1484792695330778,0.10080178494784686], [0.14939503977798488,0.10161908066393838], [0.15037780785006197,0.10243637638002989], [0.15142626929185626,0.10325367209612141], [0.15253906949973353,0.10407096781221292], [0.15371481116136612,0.10488826352830445], [0.15495206152626528,0.10570555924439595], [0.15624935944329402,0.10652285496048747], [0.15760522210883443,0.10734015067657898], [0.15901815147914886,0.10815744639267053], [0.16048664031018645,0.108974742108762], [0.16200917779740737,0.10979203782485353], [0.16358425479693292,0.11060933354094506], [0.16520993331004336,0.11142662925703659], [0.16688422700115874,0.11224392497312807], [0.16860568677181428,0.1130612206892196], [0.1703728829197052,0.11387851640531109], [0.17218440721942158,0.11469581212140262], [0.17403885930131519,0.11551310783749413], [0.17593071292964196,0.11633040355358565], [0.1778550568320067,0.11714769926967716], [0.17980807653937597,0.11796499498576866], [0.18178758544173265,0.1187822907018602], [0.1837924906630262,0.11959958641795171], [0.1858218126363723,0.12041688213404322], [0.18787312997972483,0.12123417785013477], [0.18994445911670263,0.12205147356622625], [0.19203401732136283,0.12286876928231774], [0.19414001047365512,0.12368606499840928], [0.19626134953048857,0.12450336071450081], [0.19839732373336172,0.12532065643059231], [0.20054614597911763,0.12613795214668383], [0.2027102188697154,0.12695524786277534], [0.20489645895038736,0.12777254357886683], [0.2071056985959593,0.1285898392949584], [0.20933725029121888,0.12940713501104992], [0.21159043799410046,0.1302244307271414], [0.21386545662534603,0.13104172644323292], [0.21616695565805766,0.13185902215932443], [0.21849602526410672,0.13267631787541595], [0.22085249758957576,0.13349361359150747], [0.2232371638584028,0.13431090930759898], [0.22565048466368387,0.13512820502369052], [0.2280915992825535,0.135945500739782], [0.23055962489233886,0.1367627964558735], [0.23305452139473087,0.13758009217196507], [0.2355792572479964,0.13839738788805653], [0.23813358220882275,0.13921468360414807], [0.24071656074747425,0.14003197932023959], [0.2433273963640586,0.14084927503633107], [0.24596524486026825,0.14166657075242262], [0.24863017456672842,0.14248386646851413], [0.2513289284728739,0.14330116218460567], [0.25406210594271644,0.1441184579006972], [0.2568286079689279,0.14493575361678868], [0.2596274973065834,0.1457530493328802], [0.2624581900808146,0.1465703450489717], [0.26531970812660205,0.1473876407650632], [0.26821106483019097,0.14820493648115474], [0.2711313055908074,0.14902223219724625], [0.27407950715527424,0.14983952791333777], [0.27705477691361224,0.15065682362942928], [0.2800562521635541,0.15147411934552082], [0.2830830993510777,0.15229141506161228], [0.2861345132933103,0.15310871077770383], [0.28920971638943616,0.15392600649379534], [0.2923206802678723,0.15474330220988686], [0.2954949457497638,0.1555605979259784], [0.29873543145269177,0.1563778936420699], [0.3020880630603759,0.1571951893581614], [0.30556924631118587,0.15801248507425292], [0.3091771242381686,0.15882978079034443], [0.31290731443442327,0.15964707650643595], [0.31680077310414406,0.1604643722225275], [0.3209282297369517,0.161281667938619], [0.3252820737446184,0.16209896365471044], [0.3298533407620746,0.162916259370802], [0.33463312056489414,0.16373355508689355], [0.33964400822398905,0.16455085080298504], [0.3449710651721094,0.16536814651907655], [0.35075611759025743,0.16618544223516807], [0.35753250940611797,0.16700273795125958], [0.3659658404474907,0.1678200336673511], [0.3759506203869174,0.1686373293834426], [0.3873668972264467,0.16945462509953407], [0.40009215021923283,0.17027192081562567], [0.4140056953351241,0.17108921653171713], [0.4289919281005854,0.17190651224780865]]; 

var riskFreeRate = .03;
var optimalPoint = {
    data: undefined,
    stdDev: undefined,
    ret: undefined
}
var optimalPoint3 = {
    ratio: 0,
    stdDev: undefined,
    ret: undefined
}

// Find optimal tangent point 
// sometsdf
function binaryOptimalSearch(efArray) {
    var midIndex = Math.floor(efArray.length / 2);

    var leftPoint = efArray[midIndex - 1];
    var midPoint = efArray[midIndex];
    var rightPoint = efArray[midIndex + 1];


    var leftPointSharpeRatio = (leftPoint[1] - riskFreeRate) / leftPoint[0];
    var midPointSharpeRatio = (midPoint[1] - riskFreeRate) / midPoint[0];
    var rightPointSharpeRatio = rightPoint && ((rightPoint[1] - riskFreeRate) / rightPoint[0]);

    if (efArray.length === 2) {
        //rightPoint shouldn't exist.
        if (leftPointSharpeRatio > midPointSharpeRatio) {
            return leftPoint;
        }
        if (midPointSharpeRatio > leftPointSharpeRatio) {
            return midPoint;
        }
    }
    if ((midPointSharpeRatio > leftPointSharpeRatio) && (midPointSharpeRatio > rightPointSharpeRatio)) {
        return midPoint;
    }
    if (leftPointSharpeRatio > midPointSharpeRatio) {
        var leftPortion = efArray.slice(0, midIndex + 1); // add 1 to include midindex
        return binaryOptimalSearch(leftPortion);
    }
    if (rightPointSharpeRatio > midPointSharpeRatio) {
        var rightPortion = efArray.slice(midIndex, (efArray.length) );
        return binaryOptimalSearch(rightPortion);
    }
};

// Find optimal tangent point iterative
function binaryIterativeSearch(efArray) {
    var leftIndex = 0;
    var midIndex = undefined;
    var rightIndex = efArray.length - 1;


    var leftPoint;
    var midPoint;
    var rightPoint;
    var leftPointSharpeRatio;
    var midPointSharpeRatio;
    var rightPointSharpeRatio;

    while (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
        midIndex = Math.floor((leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2);

        leftPoint = efArray[midIndex - 1];
        midPoint = efArray[midIndex];
        rightPoint = efArray[midIndex + 1];

        leftPointSharpeRatio = (leftPoint[1] - riskFreeRate) / leftPoint[0];
        midPointSharpeRatio = (midPoint[1] - riskFreeRate) / midPoint[0];
        rightPointSharpeRatio = rightPoint && ((rightPoint[1] - riskFreeRate) / rightPoint[0]);

        if ((midPointSharpeRatio > leftPointSharpeRatio) && (midPointSharpeRatio > rightPointSharpeRatio)) {
            return midPoint;
        }
        if (leftPointSharpeRatio > midPointSharpeRatio) {
            rightIndex = midIndex - 1;
        }
        if (rightPointSharpeRatio > midPointSharpeRatio) {
            leftIndex = midIndex + 1;
        }
    }
}


// Brute Force
function bruteSearch(){
    data.forEach(function (item) { // Find optimal tangent
        var stdDev = item[0];
        var ret = item[1];
        var returnPerRisk = (ret - riskFreeRate) / stdDev;
        if (returnPerRisk > optimalPoint3.ratio) {
            optimalPoint3.ratio = returnPerRisk;
            optimalPoint3.stdDev = stdDev;
            optimalPoint3.ret = ret;
        }
    }); 
}

//

var timeBinary1 = performance.now();
optimalPoint.data = binaryOptimalSearch(data);
var timeBinary2 = performance.now();
console.log('Recursive Took', (timeBinary2 - timeBinary1).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', optimalPoint.data);
optimalPoint.stdDev = optimalPoint.data[0];
optimalPoint.ret = optimalPoint.data[1];

var timeIterative1 = performance.now();
var optimalPoint2 = binaryIterativeSearch(data);
var timeIterative2 = performance.now();
console.log('Iterative Took', (timeIterative2 - timeIterative1).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', optimalPoint2);

var timeBrute1 = performance.now();
bruteSearch();
var timeBrute2 = performance.now();
console.log('Brute Took', (timeBrute2 - timeBrute1).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', optimalPoint3);
```

Comment: It looks like you've only tested this on one list. Performance characterizations look at how problems act on average over several different inputs. If you have a list where the item you're searching for is near the beginning, then on those types of problems, a brute force search may actually be faster. Only looking at one data point isn't enough to say one algorithm is faster than another.

Comment: Use a large list with random data. Each loop requires 'more work' when doing the binary searches, even if there may be far less loops overall (assuming the algorithm is correct) - Big O describes characteristics as n -> infinity. Also, timing such small/non-primed runs introduces *lots* microbenchmark noise; as a quick adjustment to get better numbers, increase the data until the slowest implementation takes ~10 seconds and then there should be an obvious difference.

Comment: Brute force is linear while BS is logarithmic, however, BS has some constant factor overhead involved that is beyond what you'll detect with such a small data set in most languages (JS seems to be one). In practical  (real-time) applications the divide and conquer approach is done until the data set gets below a certain threshold and then brute force searches are run on the smaller set. So, as others have said, you'll need to use a much larger set to see the speed enhancement. JS perf used to be a good site for running such tests, but it's been offline for a while

Comment: Im interested in the 'microbenchmark' noise as user2864740 describes.
What in the micro benchmarking make sit cost more?  I dont seem to be doing anything really different, some small math and reference setting

Comment: You might want to repeat your experiments with different sized for your `data` array. One would usually expect that the binary search would have a higher constant factor but a smaller asymptotic factor so it should be slower than sequential search for small inputs and faster for the large ones.

Comment: Some more points.  Binary gives you 7 iterations with 3 calculations each for 21 calculations.  That's more work than you'd guess.  Secondly, brute force makes good use of cache and CPU branch prediction while binary search is horrible on both.  Between these effects, it is somewhat expected that brute force is faster than binary search into lists with low hundreds of items. Also note that slice operations are `O(n)`, so your recursive version probably shouldn't do that.

Comment: Never invest time in trying to interpret the results of a microbenchmark result for any measurement taking less than five seconds (tra measuring work done in 5 s.). Describe _what_ your binary search is to find, and what is known about the input. (I _think_ subtracting `riskFreeRate` doesn't change a thing - try skipping it. Telling whether you are in a rising or falling portion doesn't require three points, but two - just continue with the "half" containing the higher value.) (Do not gamble, try to create value.)

Comment: I understand that my dataset is small and increasing the dataset will give me the type of performance I expect.  However, I did write a function to run the test 100000 times and give me the average of each test.  Like some people suggested, the results are what you expect.

btilly's response is the kind of answer I am looking for!  I never took computer science, so I dont have some insight some others have.  Also, thanks for the time complexity on slice(), I was thinking about it when I first put it in there, and I thought it would be O(1), but now I can see it's O(N).